# How do I express the action of working as a teaching assistant (i.e. TAing) professionally?

Tags: synonyms

In many emails and in-person conversations I have used the word 'TAing' as verb to quickly communicate that I am working as a teaching assistant. For example:

> I'm TAing Finite Elements this term.

Is there a more professional way of saying this concisely? Or do I just have to find alternate ways to express the same ideas?

Specifically, I'm trying to rework a bullet point from the `Skills Summary` section on my resume which currently reads:

> - Strong leadership skills demonstrated through TAing several university courses

Comment: Hmm, I think this is a bad idea, particularly on a resumé, unless your employers are all young, hip TAs.

Comment: Use a whole phrase: e.g. *Strong leadership skills demonstrated through being a teacher's assistant in several university courses.*

Comment: ... demonstrated as a T[eaching ]A[ssistant] for several university courses

Comment: TA is a recognized abbreviation for Teaching Assistant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant), it's your use of it as a verb that is too informal for a CV... I agree with @Anonym, use a whole phrase.

Comment: The title of Teaching Assistant isn't used where I'm from, but you could say that you taught, lectured or tutored the courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having applied to different types of jobs in diverse industries, I had the opportunity to edit and assess my resumé many times.

Certainly, "TAing" might confuse recruiters and HR officers as they might not know the definition of this term. Perhaps writing this as an independent previous work in your job experiences will serve your cause better.

E.g.

Teaching Assistant (Month, 20XX - Month, 20XX)

- Taught (subject) to (indicate your students) in (name of school).
- (provide additional points that indicate your other activities as a teaching assistant)

Comment: Hello Maximillian. _Is_ there a dictionary definition of TAing? An assumption that one can invent words at will would probably be seen as a negative characteristic for one involved in teaching.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't think you will find it in a dictionary, but I can attest it is in common use as jargon in US university settings, so the OP is not inventing it.  Of course, people outside this setting may not know that, and indeed may not understand the abbreviation at all.

Comment: Great, thanks. I just ended up removing that bullet point from the skills summary, and will only include it under my work experience section as you suggest.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Assessing the suitability of jargon within a domain where that jargon is used is not on-topic here. The question needs addressing to those in authority within the domain.